# In crystal report I am trying to convert datetime value to date to string

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

The following conversion is not working. I would like to see if anyone can be able to solve it.

Syntax:

```
ToText(Date({db.field}),"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

System is saying that the `date id` is required.

Comment: `ToText( Date({db.field}), "dd/MM/yyyy") `  is working fine and giving desired output.....you have to provide more info so that your issue will be more clearer to us and can give appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

however `ToText( Date({db.field}), "dd/MM/yyyy")` is working fine....

the other simplest way is :

Crystal Report Design Window->Right click on date field->format Field->Customize the date format as you want to.